# C# Web Api - IValidatableObject validationContext service provider is null

Tags: c#, validation, asp.net-web-api2, asp.net-apicontroller, ivalidatableobject

I am trying to use `IValidatableObject` validation in a web api 2 context. The `Validate` method is getting called, but the `ValidationContext` parameter passed has a method called `GetService` which always returns null because the service provider of the validation context is never set.

From all my research, we can easily configure this in the MVC framework, but I didn't find anything on how to configure it in web api 2.

How do we set the service provider to the validation context when validating models passed to an `ApiController`?

Comment: Could you please provide a link how you "easily configure this in the MVC framework". After all research I have done, it seems like MVC framework isn't using the ValidationContext.ServiceProvider at all.

Answer (score 5):

Ok, I found the solution.

The problem I had was that I was trying to completely replace the `DataAnnotationsModelValidatorProvider`, but the framework doesn't support that. In the end, I had to look for the current one in place and then register my custom factories which will setup the validation context that will be used in the `IValidatableObject`.

One important note to keep in mind, there are multiple namespaces with the `DataAnnotationsModelValidatorProvider`, but the one I need is `System.Web.Http.Validation.Providers.DataAnnotationsModelValidatorProvider`

Here what it looks like:

```
private static void SetupIoCInValidationContext(
        IServiceProvider serviceProvider)
    {
        IEnumerable<ModelValidatorProvider> modelValidatorProviders =
            GlobalConfiguration
            .Configuration.Services.GetModelValidatorProviders();

        DataAnnotationsModelValidatorProvider provider =
            (DataAnnotationsModelValidatorProvider)
                modelValidatorProviders.Single(
                    x =>
                        x.GetType()
                            .IsTypeOf(
                                typeof(DataAnnotationsModelValidatorProvider)));

        provider.RegisterDefaultAdapterFactory((providers, attribute) =>
            new CustomDataAnnotationsModelValidator(providers, attribute,
                serviceProvider));

        provider.RegisterDefaultValidatableObjectAdapterFactory(
            providers => new CustomValidatableObjectAdapter(providers, serviceProvider)
            );
    }
```

Comment: What do your implementations of CustomDataAnnotationsModelValidator and CustomValidatableObjectAdapter look like?